# Cómo puedo hacerle para seleccionar un item de mi columna tipo ComboBox? - DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, devexpress

Agregué un `ComboBox` a la columna de mi `GridViewEditingMode.Batch` y al momento de mostrar la lista no me permite seleccionar items

```
List<Productos> lstProd = new List<Productos>();          

     column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
                {
                    p.ValueType = typeof(string);
                    p.TextField = "vcDescEquipo";
                    p.ValueField = "vcIdClaveProv";
                   // p.DataSource = lstProd.ToList();
                    p.BindList(lstProd);
                });
```

[image: No permite seleccionar, solo muestra la lista.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no definía el `FieldName` de la columna, y colocarla como `UnboundType`

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T540624/gridview-can-t-select-item-from-gridviewdatacomboboxcolumn-in-batch-mode

Comment: Saludos Anahí, sería una excelente idea que del enlace que has mostrado puedas obtener código de ejemplo al que agregues a tu respuesta, de tal manera que le aumentas la calidad. Saludos :D